# How to run interactive script on shutdown

Tags: shell-script, shutdown

I'd like to check for git repositories with uncommited changes on shutdown and if there are such repositories - print them and give user ability to decide what to do - resume shutdown or abort it.

I've made a function that checks for uncommited repos. Here it is in case someone is interested

```
find_uncommited() {
        if [ -n "$1" ];then
            local root_path=$1
        else
            local root_path=$(pwd)
        fi
        eval local trash='~/.local/*'
        find $root_path -type d -not -path $trash -iname '.git' 2>/dev/null | \
            xargs -I {} $SHELL -c \
            'dir=$(dirname {});cd $dir;uncommited=$(git ls-files --modified --deleted --exclude-standard --others;git log @{push}.. 2>/dev/null);if [ -n "$uncommited" ];then echo $dir;fi'
    }
```

I know that I can put some script into `rc0` and somehow named it in such way that it would be invoked before unmounting drives, but I don't think it can be interactive.

Then there's this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747867/how-to-run-an-interactive-script-before-xserver-shutdown)

Which gaved me idea that I can some some service that would listen to dbus shutdown event from unity and ... And then what exactly? How to make this interactive for user? I can probably write python gui app for that, but maybe there is a simpler pure shell way?

Answer (score 0):

Store script in /etc/init.d

Also try to use absolute paths for your command, while quoting the other variable as well.

Give Proper File Permission to Execute